# How to get the image name of a label in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose I have below codes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./Images/img.jpg"))
my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./Images/img1.jpg"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./Images/img2.jpg"))
image_list = [my_img, my_img1, my_img2]
label1 = tk.Label(root, image=image_list[0])
print(label1.cget('image'))
```

I want to get the name of the image that is currently assigned to label1, in this example, the result I want to get is "my_img", how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: The Python variable name that held the image is utterly unknown to the widget, there's no way it can tell you that.  All you can do is look it up in a list or dict of images - but unfortunately the value you get back from the `'image`` option does not compare as equal to the original image object; instead it is equal to the `str()` of the image.  So `image_list = [str(my_img), str(my_img1), str(my_img2)]` would be a start on solving your problem.

Comment: You can use the `name` option of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, like `my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(...), name='my_img')`.  But what will you do on the name?